# QRegexp for (??)

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm fighting for some time to create a QRegExp for matching the string (??) (ie: an opening parantheses, two question marks and a closing parantheses and this should be a separate word, so before and after this can be spaces, tab, newline), The closest I came up with is `QRegExp("\\b\\(\\?\\?\\)\\b");` but even this is not matching it... Can you help me with this?

Thanks
f.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know QRegexp, but `\b` only matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, so your regex would match `(??)` only if it was directly surrounded by alnums (like `abc(??)123`).

So you need a different approach. Hoping QRegexp supports lookaround, you could use

```
QRegExp("(?<=\\s|^)\\(\\?\\?\\)(?=\\s|$)");
```

so the regex checks if there is whitespace or start/end of string before/after `(??)`.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to match the whitespace explicitly:

```
QRegExp("(?:\\s|^)\\(\\?\\?\\)(?:\\s|$)");
```

Comment: Why is the lookaround necessary? Given the string to match is known *(??)* wouldn't `(\\s|^)\\(\\?\\?\\)(\\s|$)` be enough?

Comment: @gregseth: Yes, I added that as another solution. The lookaround matches the "boundaries" approach more closely, but it's definitely not necessary.

Comment: QRegExp("(?:\\s|^)\\(\\?\\?\\)(?:\\s|$)"); is the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `\B` instead of `\b`:

```
QRegExp("\\B\\(\\?\\?\\)\\B");
```